# python command line arguments, how to pass argument as value for script

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-interface

I am having a hard time passing the arguments as value for my script in python. Here's my code:

```
import request, json, sys

def main():
    url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = json.loads(r.text)


    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage must equal [userId] [postId]")
        exit()
    for user in data:
        if user['userId'] == sys.argv[1] and user['id'] == sys.argv[2]:
            print('here i am')
            print(user)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run python -m test 1 1, nothing happens. But it does trigger when I don't have enough arguments or too many.

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Maybe you need to convert the data types of the arguments to match those in the user dict?

Comment: You don't call `main` so no code runs.

Comment: @tdelaney I wanted to keep it short, I guess I assumed that everyone knows that main is in there

Comment: @jprebys nothing happens when I run it in the command line

Comment: If you are using 2 command line args, and they don't match any values in the data dict, then nothing is supposed to happen

Comment: @jprebys print(user) runs when i hard code the values. So I assume when i hit 1 and 1 in the command line. argv[1] will equal 1 and argv[2] = 1. But it doesn't do that. The if statement inside the for loop doesn't even run.

Comment: Try printing your data as soon as you fetch it. Right after `data = json.loads(r.text)` put a `print(data)`. Probably your code is running but you don't see any visible output.

Comment: @alvaroavila yes that works. I need it to work in the command line

Comment: @user2816227 - You didn't tell us what went wrong, leaving us to guess. I just guessed the obvious.

Comment: @user2816227 Share the command line result when you run this program. If you are getting an empty result, then probably we already answered your question

Comment: @alvaroavila I am getting an empty result. But that wasn't what I was looking for. If I hard code all the values. Then everything in the user variable prints out. I guess I need to work on my explanations better. But what I was looking for is something tdelaney has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that command line arguments are strings and the data you seek are integers. You could convert `arg[1]` and `arg[2]` to integers or you could use the `argparse` module to build a more comprehensive command line parser.

```
import requests, json, sys, argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Do all the things')
    parser.add_argument('user_id', type=int,
                    help='the user id')
    parser.add_argument('id', type=int,
                    help='the other id')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = json.loads(r.text)
    
    for user in data:
        if user['userId'] == args.user_id and user['id'] == args.id:
            print('here i am')
            print(user)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```